# How to configure alias in Vite 4.4.9 + Typescript + Vue.js?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

This is my tsconfig.json and vite-config.json

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [ "src/*" ]
    }
  }
}
```

vite-config.json:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue({
        template: {
            compilerOptions: {
                isCustomElement: (tag) => {
                    // needed for when used inside a vue page
                    return tag.startsWith('file-uploader') || tag.startsWith('file-manager') || tag.startsWith('custom-image');
                }
            }
        }
    })],
    build: {
        target: "es2018",
        rollupOptions: {
            treeshake: false,
            input: {
                ...fs.readdirSync(entryDir).reduce((acc, filePath) => {
                    const componentName = getComponentName(filePath);
                    acc[componentName] = `${entryDir}/${componentName}.js`;
                    return acc;
                }, {}),
            },
            output: {
                dir: "../wwwroot/pages",
                entryFileNames: "[name].js",
                chunkFileNames: "[name].[hash].js"
            },
            resolve: {
                alias: {'@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')}
            }
        }
    }
});
```

For some reason its not resolving the following import below:
import xxxxForm from '@/components/xxxx-form.vue';

I have gone through almost 20-25 stackoverflow questions and have tried all the solution nothing working because i believe because i am working on the newest version of vite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `resolve` should be in `build`.

I am using the following

```
"vite": "^4.4.9",
"typescript": "^5.2.2",
"vue": "^3.3.4",
```

and this works for me.

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2022",
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./resources/js/*"],
            "@components/*": ["./resources/js/components/*"],
            "@composables/*": ["./resources/js/composables/*"],
            "@services/*": ["./resources/js/services/*"]
        },
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "types": ["node", "vite/client", "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/messages"]
    },
    "include": ["resources/**/*.ts", "resources/**/*.js", "resources/**/*.vue"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig, splitVendorChunkPlugin } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "node:path";
// import analyze from "rollup-plugin-analyzer";
import VueI18nPlugin from "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite";
import ckeditor5 from "@ckeditor/vite-plugin-ckeditor5";

export default defineConfig({
    envDir: "./resources/js/environments",
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                "resources/css/app.css",
                "resources/js/tenant-dashboard.ts",
                "resources/js/operator-dashboard.ts",
                "resources/js/admin-dashboard.ts",
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        ckeditor5({
            theme: require.resolve("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark"),
        }),
        VueI18nPlugin({
            // include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./resources/js/data/locales/**"),
            //jitCompilation: true,
        }),
        //splitVendorChunkPlugin(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./resources/js"),
            "@components": path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "./resources/js/components/",
            ),
            "@composables": path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "./resources/js/composables/",
            ),
            "@services": path.resolve(__dirname, "./resources/js/services/"),
            "vue-i18n": "vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm-bundler.js",
        },
    },
    build: {
        target: "es2022",
        rollupOptions: {
            // plugins: [analyze({ summaryOnly: true })],
            output: {
                manualChunks(id) {
                    if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
                        return id
                            .toString()
                            .split("node_modules/")[1]
                            .split("/")[0]
                            .toString();
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    },
    define: {
        // __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
        __VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__: true,
        __VUE_I18N_LEGACY_API__: false,
        __INTLIFY_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
        // global: "window",
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I wasn't late to the party! Within the vite definitions file `vite.config.js`, inform which folders should not be observed:

**vite.config.js**

```
. . .
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    . . .
    server: {
        watch: {
            // paths to be ignored from watching
            ignored: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, '/app/node_modules'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, '/app/vendor')
            ]
        }
    },
    . . .
});
```

**Important:** Pay attention to the path to the folders, in my case I am using Docker Container and the absolute path returned by the expression: `path.resolve(__dirname, '/app/node_modules')` is precisely `/app/node_modules` because my Container is the work folder it's `/app`.